# Android relative layout with different screens

Tags: java, android, layout

and thanks in advance. I am currently developing a game based on words, and for that purpose I have designed a custom keyboard as a relative layout.

At the moment, I am designing different resources for different screen sizes. So I have made different size resources for hdpi, mdpi and ldpi. The keyboard works excellent for hdpi screens, but it is displayed incorrectly for mdpi and ldpi screens(more so for ldpi screens). Here are the images which best describe this problem:

hdpi screen:(240 dpi, 480x800)

http://pokit.org/get/?63036a53e89f5ea526a115177fc404e8.jpg

ldpi screen:(120 dpi, 240x320)

http://pokit.org/get/?612ec561ff10fdf49cf598d170a0e672.jpg

As you can see, some of the images are larger and some are smaller even though they are all the same image(except for the "enter" key). I cannot undestand why this happens.

Here is the code of the keyboard(it is designed as a custom control).

http://pastebin.com/QJndxdex

LDPI image is 20x29 px, hdpi image is 47x69.

EDIT:
http://pastebin.com/a6dGdyay I am posting pastebin since the code is long.
Apparently, the first 5 letters are englarged for some reason, all others are displayed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Change your textSize sp to 'dp' as this also considers density of each screen which causes layouts to change dimensions. SP is preferred way by Google but it usually kills the layout that when most of it is graphics and not text.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion but there is no difference at all, any other idea?